# Can Thaumaturgy be used to create an effect which triggers later?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips, traps

I’m wondering about possible uses for the Thaumaturgy cantrip.  Can it be cast on something that has a triggering action for it to go off?

An example of what I am meaning is a shop owner casts it on the shop door.  When the door opens, a bell sounds.  I’m thinking in this situation it would need to be recast each time the door opened.

Another example would be if you are guarding a treasure and trying to catch a thief.  Cast Thaumaturgy on the treasure and when the treasure is touched, and alarm goes off, or something.  I haven’t found anything online about it.  My DM says no, another DM I know says yes.  I’m just looking for other thoughts or opinions.

Comment: I answered the question you asked in the text, rather than in the title. I don't think the title is really answerable since it's so broad. You could find lots of creative uses if you ask on a site like reddit though.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 9):

> An example of what I am meaning is a shop owner casts it on the shop door. When the door opens a bell sounds

Thaumaturgy cannot activate on a trigger or perform any kind of reaction or logic.

> I’m thinking in this situation it would need to be recast each time the door opened

Thaumaturgy effects only last for 1 minute, so even if you made the door emit a bell sound, it would only do so for 1 minute. Not a good doorbell.

> Cast Thaumaturgy on the treasure and when the treasure is touched, and alarm goes off, or something.

Again, the same problem, Thaumaturgy can't activate on a trigger, and it only lasts for 1 minute.

The spell itself lists a handful of potential uses:

> - Your voice booms up to three times as loud as normal for 1 minute.
> - You cause flames to flicker, brighten, dim, or change color for 1 minute.
> - You cause harmless tremors in the ground for 1 minute.
> - You create an instantaneous sound that originates from a point of your choice within range, such as a rumble of thunder, the cry of a raven, or ominous whispers.
> - You instantaneously cause an unlocked door or window to fly open or slam shut.
> - You alter the appearance of your eyes for 1 minute.

Some spells that may produce the effect you want are Alarm, Magic Mouth, or Glyph of Warding.

Comment: You might want to add that there is a spell that does this – *Alarm* – but it is a 1st level spell, not a cantrip.

Comment: you can also use a Glyph of Warding to Fireball the intruder trying to steal your treasure. Although that's probably not very well-suited as a doorbell for a shopowner, even if your shop is on the plane of fire where most people would be immune to the damage ^^

Comment: Magic Mouth can also be used to create notifications and alarms

Comment: Thanks J.E PixelMaster Odo, I added the suggestions.